# Strange Issue with PHP's fopen, "Numerical result out of range"

Tags: php, file, file-io, fopen

I'm trying to open a file using fopen, and I am getting the error:

```
Warning:  fopen(/var/www/views/images/favicon.gif): failed to open stream:
Numerical result out of range
```

The file exists at the provided path. I couldn't find any documentation on the error to fix it. Any thoughts?

Comment: How about showing us the code snippet?

Comment: Agreed - it may be an error caused by something else in nearby code I guess.

Comment: This might be a filesystem related issue. chroot, permissions, possibly even just a file descriptor opened twice. Try specifying the filename relatively to the script first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was trying to use

```
fopen($file, FOPEN_READ)
```

When all I had to do was change it to:

```
fopen($file, 'r')
```

And that fixed it.

Comment: Ugh! Why does PHP have built-in constants for some things like `preg_match()`, but not for others such as this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you access the file directly? What kind of information does `getimagesize()` return on the file? It seems really odd and I'm having no luck getting that result.